# Multiple AVPlayer simultaneous playback on one view

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have four AVPlayer layers on a single view. All 4 plays streams from remote server.

```
streamView1 = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:VideoStreamURL1];
layer1 = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.streamView1]
[self.layer addSublayer: layer1];
```

I am calling all 4 player on single action and have pause,stop and playback timer functionalities as well. Now the video playback starts at different time. I need all 4 video and the timer to start at the same time.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: i have used AVPlayer's seekToTime & setRate combination make this work. Give that a try with NSTimer.